# Django and docker: outputting information to console

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm using Django, which I run in a Docker container. There is something happening in my view that I can not understand. There are some *for* statements and conditional statements and I'd like to see exactly where things go awry. The easiest way for me to do this, is if I can output some variables to the console. Is this possible in Django?

Something like:

```
for item in items:
   output-to-console("Running item ")+str(item.id)

   if item.active:
        output-to-console(str(item.id) + " is active")
```

Is this possible? I know there are debugging tools but it seems overkill in my situation if some output-to-console tool exists...

Comment: try `docker logs CONTANERID --follow` to see logs of the running container. ex: `docker logs 85efe36833 --follow`

Comment: Thanks -- I can see the logs, but I don't know how to make Django output the variables I'm interested in into the console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to configure a logger. [Here's a simple example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#examples).
The difference is that you can use `logging.StreamHandler` as a handler's class to have a specific logger print to stdout. This will print every log into the console:

```
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '[DJANGO] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                          '%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '*': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            }
        },
    }
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('something here')
```

And when you follow the logs of your container `docker[-compose] logs -f tail==100` you'll see everything that logger prints.