# Django logger is not shown that runs on Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

`logger.debug()` and `print()` are not shown on a Django project that runs on Docker. Any other operations are correct.

Is my recognition correct that the logs show up on the terminal window that runs `docker-compose up`?

I tried [outputting resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004910/django-and-docker-outputting-information-to-console/52010919), but it not work for me.

My settings are below.

directory

```sh
Project
    ├── Service_ID
    │       ├── root
    │            ├──settings.py
    |             
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── docker
        ├── mysql
        │   ├── Dockerfile
        │   └── my.cnf
        ├── nginx
        │   ├── default.conf
        │   └── uwsgi_params
        └── python
            ├── Dockerfile
            └── requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
...

  web:
    image: nginx:1.21.3-alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./Service_ID:/workspace
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/uwsgi_params:/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
    working_dir: /workspace
    depends_on:
      - root

  root:
    build: ./docker/python
    command: uwsgi --socket :8001 --module root.wsgi --py-autoreload 1 --logto /tmp/tmp.log
    volumes:
      - ./Service_ID:/workspace
    expose:
      - "8001"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db-store:
```

python/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
ADD requirements.txt /workspace/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /workspace/
```

Service_ID/root/settings.py

```py
IS_ON_LOG_FILE = True
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'file': {
            'format': '\t'.join([
                "[%(levelname)s]",
                "%(message)s",
            ])
        },
        'console': {
            'format': '\t'.join([
                "[%(levelname)s]",
                "%(message)s",
            ])
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django.log'),
            'formatter': 'file',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
    },

    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'file'] if IS_ON_LOG_FILE else ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you looked within the container for the `django.log` file? Do you have the ENV variable set for the file to output? Do you have settings in `root.wsgi` that changes where output should go for stream/console? You would use `docker-compose logs root` to see the logs (stream/console) output.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I already have read `django.log`. But it is inconvenient to read it, so I need to read the same texts at the console. Could you tell me more detail about `root.wsgi`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of seeing consoles like a project without Docker, I use [Django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). It has a Log section.