# Django docker logging

Tags: python, django, docker

I am running docker on my Mac.  I am having an issue with my views.py and I am trying to print out to the Mac docker desktop some messages to try to debug my code.  I have followed

> [Django and docker: outputting information to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004910/django-and-docker-outputting-information-to-console/52010919)

and it doesn't seem to work for me.  The only thing that gets printed out to the docker desktop logs is just errors when they occur,  Normally all I get is just the 200 ok from the http request.  I have used the print statement and the info statement and neither of them print out.

```
------------------------------------ setttings.py ------------------------------------ 

from pathlib import Path
import os
import logging.config
import json


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True



#Logging Config

LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '[DJANGO] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                          '%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '*': {
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
            }
        },
    }

------------------------------------ views.py ------------------------------------ 

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .login_model import LoginForm
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Create your views here.

def load_index(request):
    logger.info('in index from logger\n')
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def login(request):
    logger.info('in login from logger\n')
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def login_validator(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(f"method is post")
        logger.info('in login validator')

    print("returning in login validator")
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: How do you start django in the container ? What it does it basically log to the console.

Comment: I call it from the Dockerfile `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: All I get from the console besides any errors when they occur is `[10/Feb/2022 20:14:20] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 5133`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why I am not able to see the logs on the Docker console, but as a workaround stdout.write works.  Removed all the log stuff from the settings.py and added the following to the views.py file.

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Message goes here. \n")
```

in the docker console I am now able to see the messages.